# How to get the date that your managed package was created?

Tags: managed-package

How do I get the year that a version of a managed package was created?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible programatically. The CreatedDate field on the corresponding PackageLicense field in an customer should tell you the install date for that specific org.

In the packaging org I believe you can find it in the UI of the Setup > Create > Packages screen, but again that requires human inspection and isn't part of an API that I know of.